# Как запустить функцию flask без отслеживания перехода по адресу

Tags: python, html, flask

Я хочу запускать серверную функцию не вызывая перехода на другую страницу, например:

template.html:

```
<a href="вызов моей функции(например onclick()), но страничка не должна никак меняться">Привет!</a>
```

views.py:

```
def onclick():
   #мой код
```

Comment: Вернуть http ответ 204

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

Comment: Не подскажите как это записать в виде air.route или что то такое